# Is Messenger app data saved in phone storage?

Tags: android, apk, mobile-application

I am curious about something. Are Facebook Messenger app conversations stored in Android device storage ? If yes, where are they stored exactly ?

Comment: No they are not.

Answer (score -1):

YES,when you go to your internal storage and go to apps u will find all the apps on the system but when u click on messenger the size of the app will be more compared to size when u download it from playstore or appstore which means that the size has increased because of your messages or photos, that's where your data for messenger or any other app is stored.

Comment: `... which means that the size has increased because of your messages or photos ...` No, that means that the app has been **installed** (the apk has been extracted) and that some cache has been written.